# My JSP is using EL its not getting the getLocation property

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb, el, javabeans

The class 'Beans.SidePanelBean' does not have the property "getLocation" is the exact error.
I'm follow the naming convention accordingly (I think) and I am still getting this error.
My JSP

```
<li>Pick Up Location</li>
 <ul>${spb.getLocation}</ul>
```

My Servlet:

```
String strlocation = request.getParameter("location");
spb.setLocation(strlocation);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("spb", spb);
```

My Bean:

```
    public SidePanelBean(){}
    String location;
public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the getter is `getLocation()`, then the name of the property is `location`, not `getLocation`. Use

```
<ul>${spb.location}</ul>
```

Comment: Bah I just saw my mistake as you answered. Its a long day today hehe